# Django. Why I cant pass parametr from abstract model class to child model field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have many classes with same field named `state`, which is `CharField` with choices. And all of this classes inherit from one abstract class. I decided to put choices variable to this abstract class:

```
class UsefullAbstractClass(models.Model):
    NEW = 'new'
    ACTUAL = 'actual'
    DELETE = 'delete'

    STATE_CHOICES = (
        (NEW, 'new'),
        (ACTUAL, 'actual'),
        (DELETE, 'delete'))

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Here my child class:

```
ChildClass(UsefullAbstractClass):
    state = models.CharField(
            max_length=100,
            choices=STATE_CHOICES)
```

And I got

> name 'STATE_CHOICES' is not defined

Then I use `manage.py shell` for check this variable exists. And all child class instanses has this variable

```
>>> c = ChildClass.objects.all()
>>> c[0].STATE_CHOICES
(('new', 'new'), ('actual', 'actual'), ('delete', 'delete'))
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you can define the state field in `UsefullAbstractClass` instead of `ChildClass`

Comment: @Pavan yes I can, but in some other models i have different choises for state, and want to just overide this variable. And I want to understand, why is this inherit didnt work in field, but I can see this variable in all instance of this class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ChildClass(UsefullAbstractClass):
    state = models.CharField(
            max_length=100,
            choices=UsefullAbstractClass.STATE_CHOICES)
```

Variables defined in the class definition are class variables; they are shared by all instances. To create instance variables, they can be set in a method with self.name = value. Both class and instance variables are accessible through the notation `self.name`.

You can access it in any methods of ChildClass like `self.STATE_CHOICES`.
That's why it worked for `c[0].STATE_CHOICES`

So it is only accessible with the instances (`self.variable_name`). If you want to access it outside the methods then you should do `class.variable_name`.

For more details please check the link http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions

Comment: Thank. It works, but I realy want to understand, why I cant just use `STATE_CHOICES`. If you can explain, it will be nice

Comment: Because it's defined in UsefulAbstractClass.